# importing dataset in Cloud Analyst

Tags: javascript

I am a student of Bs computer Science and I am doing research in cloud Computing Using Cloud Analyst and I need help regarding Cloud Analyst. We simulated 6 UserBbase that corresponds to six zones with a specific time zone, and most users use the app in the evening for about 2 hours after work. That every 5 minutes, each user sends a new request while online:

[image: userbase configuration parameters]

How can we get this original data or what is the source of this data?